# Mapping Exception: Unable to read XML when externalizing a named native query in JPA 2.0

Tags: jpa-2.0, external, named-query

I have some long queries (text wise) that I am trying to externalize into an orm.xml file for readability and maintainability purposes but I keep getting a **mapping exception: Unable to read XML.**
This is what I have:

**persistence.xml** in src/main/resources/META-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <mapping-file>edu/kdc/visioncards/pojo/orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <class>edu.kdc.visioncards.pojo.AttendanceBreakDown</class>              

    <properties>            
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>                     
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>        
</persistence>
```

An **orm.xml** as follows under src/main/resources/edu/kdc/visioncards/pojo as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm 
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd" 
version="2.0">

    <package>edu.kdc.visioncards.pojo</package>

    <named-native-query name="attendanceDetailsBySchoolAndGradingPeriod"
                    result-class="edu.kdc.visioncards.pojo.AttendanceBreakDown" 
                    result-set-mapping="attendanceBreakDownResults">
        <query>
         select
                a.student_name as student_name
               ,a.student_id as student_id
               ,a.enrollment_status as enrollment_status
               ,a.attendance_days as attendance_days
               ,a.Attendance_Level as attendance_level
               ,b.authorized_absences as auth_abs
               ,nvl(c.unx_abs,0) as unx_abs
               ,nvl(d.x_abs, 0) as x_abs
               ,nvl(e.tardies, 0) as tardies
               ,a.att_pct
          from
              (select
                   s.student_name
                  ,s.student_id
                  ,s.student_activity_indicator as enrollment_status
                  ,sum(fas.attendance_days) as attendance_days
                  ,round((sum(fas.attendance_value) / sum(fas.attendance_days))* 100,2) as att_pct
                  ,case when(round((sum(fas.attendance_value) / sum(fas.attendance_days))* 100,2) &lt;= 87)
                                then 'Intervene'
                                when(round((sum(fas.attendance_value) / sum(fas.attendance_days))* 100,2) >87 and
                                     round((sum(fas.attendance_value) / sum(fas.attendance_days))* 100,2) &lt;= 89.9)
                                then 'Concern'
                                when(round((sum(fas.attendance_value) / sum(fas.attendance_days))* 100,2) >=90 and
                                     round((sum(fas.attendance_value) / sum(fas.attendance_days))* 100,2) &lt;= 95)
                                then 'Baseline'
                                else 'Is Clean'
                           end AS Attendance_Level
                  from K12INTEL_DW.ftbl_attendance_stumonabssum fas
                   inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_students s
                       on fas.student_key = s.student_key
                  inner join K12INTEL_DW.dtbl_schools ds
                      on fas.school_key = ds.school_key
                  inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_school_dates dsd
                      on fas.school_dates_key = dsd.school_dates_key
                  where dsd.rolling_local_school_yr_number = 0
                  and ds.school_code = ?
                  and s.student_activity_indicator = 'Active'
                  and fas.LOCAL_GRADING_PERIOD = ?
                  and s.student_current_grade_level = ?
                  group by s.student_id, s.student_name, s.student_activity_indicator
                  having (sum(fas.attendance_value) / sum(fas.attendance_days)) &lt; .95
               ) a
          inner join
                  (select t.student_id
                   ,sum(t.auth_abs) as authorized_absences
                  from(
                      select dstud.student_id
                             ,case when(fas.excused_authorized) in ('NA', 'No')
                             then 0 else 1
                             end as auth_abs
                      from K12INTEL_DW.ftbl_attendance_stumonabssum fas
                      inner join K12INTEL_DW.dtbl_schools ds
                          on fas.school_key = ds.school_key
                      inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_students dstud
                          on dstud.student_key = fas.student_key
                      inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_school_dates dsd
                          on dsd.school_dates_key = fas.school_dates_key
                      where dsd.rolling_local_school_yr_number = 0
                      and dstud.student_activity_indicator = 'Active'
                      and ds.school_code = ?
                      and fas.LOCAL_GRADING_PERIOD = ?
                      and dstud.student_current_grade_level = ?
                   ) t
                  group by t.student_id)b
          on b.student_id = a.student_id
          left outer join
                      ( select dstud.student_id,
                               count(fas.excused_absence) as unx_abs
                          from K12INTEL_DW.ftbl_attendance_stumonabssum fas
                          inner join K12INTEL_DW.dtbl_schools ds
                              on fas.school_key = ds.school_key
                          inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_students dstud
                              on dstud.student_key = fas.student_key
                          inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_school_dates dsd
                              on dsd.school_dates_key = fas.school_dates_key
                          where dsd.rolling_local_school_yr_number = 0
                          and dstud.student_activity_indicator = 'Active'
                          and fas.excused_absence = 'Un-excused absence'
                          and ds.school_code = ?
                          and fas.LOCAL_GRADING_PERIOD = ?
                          and dstud.student_current_grade_level = ?
                          group by dstud.student_id
                       ) c
          on c.student_id = a.student_id
          left outer join
              (select dstud.student_id, count(fas.excused_absence) as x_abs
                  from K12INTEL_DW.ftbl_attendance_stumonabssum fas
                  inner join K12INTEL_DW.dtbl_schools ds
                      on fas.school_key = ds.school_key
                  inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_students dstud
                      on dstud.student_key = fas.student_key
                  inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_school_dates dsd
                      on dsd.school_dates_key = fas.school_dates_key
                  where dsd.rolling_local_school_yr_number = 0
                  and dstud.student_activity_indicator = 'Active'
                  and fas.excused_absence = 'Excused absence'
                  and ds.school_code = ?
                  and fas.LOCAL_GRADING_PERIOD = ?
                  and dstud.student_current_grade_level = ?
                  group by dstud.student_id) d
          on d.student_id = a.student_id
          left outer join
              (select s.student_id
                     ,sum(a.attendance_value) tardies
                from k12intel_dw.ftbl_attendance a
                inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_school_dates sd
                    on a.school_dates_key = sd.school_dates_key
                inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_students s
                  on a.student_key = s.student_key
                inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_schools  sc
                    on sc.school_key = s.school_key
                where 1=1
                and sd.rolling_local_school_yr_number = 0
                and a.attendance_type in ('LA','LP','LF')
                and sc.school_code= ?
                and s.student_current_grade_level = ?
                group by s.student_id) e
          on e.student_id = a.student_id 
        </query>                     
    </named-native-query>

    <sql-result-set-mapping name="attendanceBreakDownResults">
        <entity-result entity-class="edu.kdc.visioncards.pojo.AttendanceBreakDown">
            <field-result name="studentName" column="student_name"/>
            <field-result name="pupilId" column="student_id"/>
            <field-result name="enrollmentStatus" column="enrollment_status"/>
            <field-result name="attendanceLevel" column="attendance_level"/>
            <field-result name="attendanceDays" column="attendance_days"/>
            <field-result name="authorizedAbsences" column="auth_abs"/>
            <field-result name="unexcusedAbsences" column="unx_abs"/>
            <field-result name="excusedAbsences" column="x_abs"/>
            <field-result name="tardies" column="tardies"/>
            <field-result name="attendancePct" column="att_pct"/>
        </entity-result>
    </sql-result-set-mapping>

</entity-mappings>
```

This is how I **Inject the EntityManager into my DAO**

```
@Repository
public class K12DaoImpl implements K12DaoManager{   

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<AttendanceBreakDown> getAttendanceBreakDownBySchoolAndGP(int school, String gradingPeriod, String gradeLevel) {

    Object values[] = new Object[]{new Integer(school), gradingPeriod, gradeLevel,
                                   new Integer(school), gradingPeriod, gradeLevel,
                                   new Integer(school), gradingPeriod, gradeLevel,
                                   new Integer(school), gradingPeriod, gradeLevel,
                                   new Integer(school), gradeLevel
                                  };

    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("attendanceDetailsBySchoolAndGradingPeriod");

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        query.setParameter(i, values[i]);
    }

    List<AttendanceBreakDown> list = query.getResultList();
    return list;
}
```

}

When I do a **mvn clean tomcat:run** I get an **InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML** It seems like its not finding the **orm.xml** anywhere as I cannot see where the mapping error is.

I have externalized successfully queries using Hibernate before by having hbm files that map queries to objects and have those hbm files referenced in the hibernate.cfg.xml but now I want to use JPA 2.0 straight by using EntityManager.

**Adding Stack Trace per comment below (THIS STACK TRACE is from using XML files instead of Annotations**

```
2011-12-01 14:32:49,387 [Thread-2] ERROR org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger - Error parsing XML (6) : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'entity-mappings'.
2011-12-01 14:32:49,434 [Thread-2] ERROR org.hibernate.util.xml.ErrorLogger - Error parsing XML (2) : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'entity-mappings'.
2011-12-01 14:32:49,450 [Thread-2] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'k12DaoImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\stsworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\visioncards\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\stsworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\visioncards\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:529)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:495)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:629)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:338)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    at org.hibernate.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addXMLEntities(Ejb3Configuration.java:734)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'entity-mappings'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1915)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3103)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:75)
    ... 41 more
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE: Trying to do it Annotation Based**

So I have commented out the  tag in persistence.xml and I created the following annotations in my POJO

```
package edu.kdc.visioncards.pojo;

import javax.persistence.EntityResult;
import javax.persistence.FieldResult;
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;

@NamedNativeQuery(
    name="attendanceDetailsBySchoolAndGradingPeriod",
    query="SAME QUERY HERE AS THE ONE IN ORM.XML ABOVE",
    resultClass = AttendanceBreakDown.class,
    resultSetMapping="attendanceBreakDownResults"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="attendanceBreakDownResults",
        entities=@EntityResult(entityClass=edu.kdc.visioncards.pojo.AttendanceBreakDown.class,          
        fields={
            @FieldResult(name="studentName", column="student_name"),
            @FieldResult(name="studentName", column="student_name"),
            @FieldResult(name="pupilId", column="student_id"),
            @FieldResult(name="enrollmentStatus", column="enrollment_status"),
            @FieldResult(name="attendanceLevel", column="attendance_level"),
            @FieldResult(name="attendanceDays", column="attendance_days"),
            @FieldResult(name="authorizedAbsences", column="auth_abs"),
            @FieldResult(name="unexcusedAbsences", column="unx_abs"),
            @FieldResult(name="excusedAbsences", column="x_abs"),
            @FieldResult(name="tardies", column="tardies"),
            @FieldResult(name="attendancePct", column="att_pct")
        }
    )
)

public class AttendanceBreakDown {

   private String studentName;
    private String pupilId;
    private String enrollmentStatus;
    private String attendanceLevel;
    private String attendanceDays;
    private String authorizedAbsences;
    private String unexcusedAbsences;
    private String excusedAbsences;
    private String tardies;
    private String attendancePct;

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public String getPupilId() {
        return pupilId;
    }

    public void setPupilId(String pupilId) {
        this.pupilId = pupilId;
    }

    public String getEnrollmentStatus() {
        return enrollmentStatus;
    }

    public void setEnrollmentStatus(String enrollmentStatus) {
        this.enrollmentStatus = enrollmentStatus;
    }

    public String getAttendanceLevel() {
        return attendanceLevel;
    }

    public void setAttendanceLevel(String attendanceLevel) {
        this.attendanceLevel = attendanceLevel;
    }

    public String getAttendanceDays() {
        return attendanceDays;
    }

    public void setAttendanceDays(String attendanceDays) {
        this.attendanceDays = attendanceDays;
    }

    public String getAuthorizedAbsences() {
        return authorizedAbsences;
    }

    public void setAuthorizedAbsences(String authorizedAbsences) {
        this.authorizedAbsences = authorizedAbsences;
    }

    public String getUnexcusedAbsences() {
        return unexcusedAbsences;
    }

    public void setUnexcusedAbsences(String unexcusedAbsences) {
        this.unexcusedAbsences = unexcusedAbsences;
    }

    public String getExcusedAbsences() {
        return excusedAbsences;
    }

    public void setExcusedAbsences(String excusedAbsences) {
        this.excusedAbsences = excusedAbsences;
    }

    public String getTardies() {
        return tardies;
    }

    public void setTardies(String tardies) {
        this.tardies = tardies;
    }

    public String getAttendancePct() {
        return attendancePct;
    }

    public void setAttendancePct(String attendancePct) {
        this.attendancePct = attendancePct;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("AttendanceBreakDown [studentName=").append(studentName)
                .append(", pupilId=").append(pupilId)
                .append(", enrollmentStatus=").append(enrollmentStatus)
                .append(", attendanceLevel=").append(attendanceLevel)
                .append(", attendanceDays=").append(attendanceDays)
                .append(", authorizedAbsences=").append(authorizedAbsences)
                .append(", unexcusedAbsences=").append(unexcusedAbsences)
                .append(", excusedAbsences=").append(excusedAbsences)
                .append(", tardies=").append(tardies)
                .append(", attendancePct=").append(attendancePct).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }    
}
```

With the annotation based style I get a:

```
Named query not found: attendanceDetailsBySchoolAndGradingPeriod; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Named query not found: attendanceDetailsBySchoolAndGradingPeriod
```

With the following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:286)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:15)
edu.kdc.visioncards.dao.K12DaoImpl.getAttendanceBreakDownBySchoolAndGP(K12DaoImpl.java:32)
edu.kdc.visioncards.service.K12ManagerImpl.getAttendanceBreakDownBySchoolAndGradingPeriod(K12ManagerImpl.java:22)
edu.kdc.visioncards.web.PrimerController.test(PrimerController.java:34)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Comment: What's the exception stack trace? And what's the query?

Comment: Hi JB Nizet I have added the strack trace but not the query for privacy (3rd party client db). The query that I have it mapped successfully using the same pojo and Hiberante as a JPA implementation. But now that I want to do JPA directly something seems not configured properly. If you cannot deduce from stack trace i'll paste the query

Comment: @JB Nizet I have added the SQL like you suggested and the new stack trace I am getting. I have also tried to do it Annotation Based but I ve got a Named Query not found Exception. Any help will be much appreciated as I have been stuck for many hours already. All this hype on Grails, Roo etc...very easy to get started but once you do something a little bit of the quick demos the configuration learning curve is very steep. Seems very simple no? A named query, a mapping resultset to an object and done! But no, no no ....big roadblock and I do not know what it is.

Comment: You have >87 and >=90 in your query, resulting in invalid XML. Encode them to &gt;87 and &gt;=90. And be sure to use an XML editor which validates the XML.

Comment: Weird that query worked in Hibernate when put in a hbm file. It only really complained on the < but not on >. I will give it a try. Additionally Michael Keith (author of Pro JPA 2.0) just told me that if I name the file orm.xml it needs to be in the meta-inf directory. And also told me that when you are using annotations then you must put them on an entity since JPA provider will not find them on your spring bean. So my question is can I not run a query in JPA and map it to an object tat is not an @Entity?

Comment: You're right. JPA annotations are on JPA entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put the answer to this problem on this other question that I  asked differently:

[How to load hbm files on a JPA 2.0 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363647/how-to-load-a-hibernate-xxx-hbm-cfg-file-in-a-jpa-2-0-project)