# How to load a Hibernate 'xxx.hbm.cfg' file in a JPA 2.0 project?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, named-query

I have just started a Spring Roo application with Hibernate as a JPA2.0 provider. I am using the jars as follows:

**hibernate-core-3.6.4.Final.jar**

**hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.jar**

**hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.4.Final.jar**

**hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar**

**hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar**

I am using Annotations to handle the transactional aspect of the application, no problem there.

But there are other parts of the application that require very complex queries, and the way I had it handled in Hibernate before was to create a mapping file e.g (mybigdwquery.hbm.xml) where I would specify my query and its mapping object, a POJO. Not an @Entity. This works fine.

However, Through another question that I previously posted, I found out that in JPA 2.0 you cannot have queries mapped to a POJO, everything has to be mapped to an @Entity (a db table no?).

**So my question is as follows:**

Is there any way that I can have my **'mybigdwquery.hbm.xml'** file loaded in my persistence.xml as a hbm.xml so that I can call the named query?

My persistence.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>             
        <properties>
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/> -->
            <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->            
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>                                   
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>    
</persistence>
```

The file that I need loaded:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="edu.kdc.visioncards.pojo">

    <class name="AttendanceBreakDown">
        <cache usage="read-only" />
        <id name="studentName"/>
        <property name="pupilId"></property>
        <property name="enrollmentStatus"></property>
        <property name="attendanceLevel"></property>
        <property name="attendanceDays"></property>
        <property name="authorizedAbsences"></property>
        <property name="unexcusedAbsences"></property>
        <property name="excusedAbsences"></property>
        <property name="tardies"></property>
        <property name="attendancePct"></property>
    </class>

    <sql-query name="attendanceDetailsBySchoolAndGradingPeriod">
        <return alias="attSchGr" class="edu.kdc.visioncards.pojo.AttendanceBreakDown">
         <return-property name="studentName" column="student_name"/>
         <return-property name="pupilId" column="student_id"/>
         <return-property name="enrollmentStatus" column="enrollment_status"/>
         <return-property name="attendanceLevel" column="attendance_Level"/>
         <return-property name="attendanceDays" column="attendance_days"/>
         <return-property name="authorizedAbsences" column="auth_abs"/>
         <return-property name="unexcusedAbsences" column="unx_abs"/>
         <return-property name="excusedAbsences" column="x_abs"/>
         <return-property name="tardies" column="tardies"/>
         <return-property name="attendancePct" column="att_pct"/>
         </return>
          select
                a.student_name
               ,a.student_id
               ,a.enrollment_status
               ,a.attendance_days
               ,a.Attendance_Level
               ,b.authorized_absences as auth_abs
               ,nvl(c.unx_abs,0) as unx_abs
               ,nvl(d.x_abs, 0) as x_abs
               ,nvl(e.tardies, 0) as tardies
               ,a.att_pct
          from
              (select
                   s.student_name
                  ,s.student_id
                  ,s.student_activity_indicator as enrollment_status
                  ,sum(fas.attendance_days) as attendance_days
                  ,round((sum(fas.attendance_value) / sum(fas.attendance_days))* 100,2) as att_pct
                  ,case when(round((sum(fas.attendance_value) / sum(fas.attendance_days))* 100,2) &lt;= 87)
                                then 'Intervene'
                                when(round((sum(fas.attendance_value) / sum(fas.attendance_days))* 100,2) >87 and
                                     round((sum(fas.attendance_value) / sum(fas.attendance_days))* 100,2) &lt;= 89.9)
                                then 'Concern'
                                when(round((sum(fas.attendance_value) / sum(fas.attendance_days))* 100,2) >=90 and
                                     round((sum(fas.attendance_value) / sum(fas.attendance_days))* 100,2) &lt;= 95)
                                then 'Baseline'
                                else 'Is Clean'
                           end AS Attendance_Level
                  from K12INTEL_DW.ftbl_attendance_stumonabssum fas
                   inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_students s
                       on fas.student_key = s.student_key
                  inner join K12INTEL_DW.dtbl_schools ds
                      on fas.school_key = ds.school_key
                  inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_school_dates dsd
                      on fas.school_dates_key = dsd.school_dates_key
                  where dsd.rolling_local_school_yr_number = 0
                  and ds.school_code = ?
                  and s.student_activity_indicator = 'Active'
                  and fas.LOCAL_GRADING_PERIOD = ?
                  and s.student_current_grade_level = ?
                  group by s.student_id, s.student_name, s.student_activity_indicator
                  having (sum(fas.attendance_value) / sum(fas.attendance_days)) &lt; .95
               ) a
          inner join
                  (select t.student_id
                   ,sum(t.auth_abs) as authorized_absences
                  from(
                      select dstud.student_id
                             ,case when(fas.excused_authorized) in ('NA', 'No')
                             then 0 else 1
                             end as auth_abs
                      from K12INTEL_DW.ftbl_attendance_stumonabssum fas
                      inner join K12INTEL_DW.dtbl_schools ds
                          on fas.school_key = ds.school_key
                      inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_students dstud
                          on dstud.student_key = fas.student_key
                      inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_school_dates dsd
                          on dsd.school_dates_key = fas.school_dates_key
                      where dsd.rolling_local_school_yr_number = 0
                      and dstud.student_activity_indicator = 'Active'
                      and ds.school_code = ?
                      and fas.LOCAL_GRADING_PERIOD = ?
                      and dstud.student_current_grade_level = ?
                   ) t
                  group by t.student_id)b
          on b.student_id = a.student_id
          left outer join
                      ( select dstud.student_id,
                               count(fas.excused_absence) as unx_abs
                          from K12INTEL_DW.ftbl_attendance_stumonabssum fas
                          inner join K12INTEL_DW.dtbl_schools ds
                              on fas.school_key = ds.school_key
                          inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_students dstud
                              on dstud.student_key = fas.student_key
                          inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_school_dates dsd
                              on dsd.school_dates_key = fas.school_dates_key
                          where dsd.rolling_local_school_yr_number = 0
                          and dstud.student_activity_indicator = 'Active'
                          and fas.excused_absence = 'Un-excused absence'
                          and ds.school_code = ?
                          and fas.LOCAL_GRADING_PERIOD = ?
                          and dstud.student_current_grade_level = ?
                          group by dstud.student_id
                       ) c
          on c.student_id = a.student_id
          left outer join
              (select dstud.student_id, count(fas.excused_absence) as x_abs
                  from K12INTEL_DW.ftbl_attendance_stumonabssum fas
                  inner join K12INTEL_DW.dtbl_schools ds
                      on fas.school_key = ds.school_key
                  inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_students dstud
                      on dstud.student_key = fas.student_key
                  inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_school_dates dsd
                      on dsd.school_dates_key = fas.school_dates_key
                  where dsd.rolling_local_school_yr_number = 0
                  and dstud.student_activity_indicator = 'Active'
                  and fas.excused_absence = 'Excused absence'
                  and ds.school_code = ?
                  and fas.LOCAL_GRADING_PERIOD = ?
                  and dstud.student_current_grade_level = ?
                  group by dstud.student_id) d
          on d.student_id = a.student_id
          left outer join
              (select s.student_id
                     ,sum(a.attendance_value) tardies
                from k12intel_dw.ftbl_attendance a
                inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_school_dates sd
                    on a.school_dates_key = sd.school_dates_key
                inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_students s
                  on a.student_key = s.student_key
                inner join k12intel_dw.dtbl_schools  sc
                    on sc.school_key = s.school_key
                where 1=1
                and sd.rolling_local_school_yr_number = 0
                and a.attendance_type in ('LA','LP','LF')
                and sc.school_code= ?
                and s.student_current_grade_level = ?
                group by s.student_id) e
          on e.student_id = a.student_id
    </sql-query>   

</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is my DAO:

```
@Repository
public class K12DaoImpl implements K12DaoManager{   

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

//  @Autowired
//    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
//
//    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
//      this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
//  }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<AttendanceBreakDown> getAttendanceBreakDownBySchoolAndGP(int school, String gradingPeriod, String gradeLevel) {

        Object values[] = new Object[]{new Integer(school), gradingPeriod, gradeLevel,
                                       new Integer(school), gradingPeriod, gradeLevel,
                                       new Integer(school), gradingPeriod, gradeLevel,
                                       new Integer(school), gradingPeriod, gradeLevel,
                                       new Integer(school), gradeLevel
                                      };
//        Call Named Query through JPA
//        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("attendanceDetailsBySchoolAndGradingPeriod");
//        
//        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
//          query.setParameter(i, values[i]);
//        }
//        
//        List<AttendanceBreakDown> list = query.getResultList();
//        

//        Call Named Query through Hibernate's SessionFactory        
//        org.hibernate.Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("attendanceDetailsBySchoolAndGradingPeriod");
//        
//        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
//          query.setParameter(i, values[i]);
//        }
//        
//        List<AttendanceBreakDown> list =  query.list();

        //Call Named Query through HibernateTemplate
        //List<AttendanceBreakDown> list =  getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery("attendanceDetailsBySchoolAndGradingPeriod", values); 

        //return list;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Before, without using persistence.xml I had the typical hibernate.cfg.xml settings inside an applicationContext-datasource with it session factory, the session factory tied to the datasource etc.. an everything work fine.

Now I have persistence.xml, no more SessionFactory, EntityManager now.

How can I load hbm.xml files and execute them through Hibernate rather than through JPA 2.0 ?

If you see the commented code in the DAO If I was using a Hibernate config calling the named query through the HibernateTemplate (extending HibernateDaoSupport) was working. What would the code be like now ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own question. To make it work this is what I have done:

1. <strike>Use **<mapping-file>...hbm.xml</mapping-file>** inside **<persistence-unit>** in **persistence.xml**</strike>. I really did not have the use the **<mapping-file>...hbm.xml</mapping-file>** tag as that was giving me all sorts of exceptions one of them was DuplicateMappingException. According to the docs I also thought I had to use that tag, but it turns out that you do not have to.
2. Created **edu/kdc/visioncards/pojo/AttendanceBreakDown.hbm.xml** under **src/main/resources**
3. Finally in my **DAO**, I have as follows:

   ```
   @Override
   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   public List<AttendanceBreakDown> getAttendanceBreakDownBySchoolAndGP(int school, String gradingPeriod, String gradeLevel) {
        Object values[] = new Object[]{new Integer(school), gradingPeriod, gradeLevel,
                                  new Integer(school), gradingPeriod, gradeLevel,
                                  new Integer(school), gradingPeriod, gradeLevel,
                                  new Integer(school), gradingPeriod, gradeLevel,
                                  new Integer(school), gradeLevel
                                 };

        org.hibernate.Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
        org.hibernate.Query query = session.getNamedQuery("attendanceDetailsBySchoolAndGradingPeriod");
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
           query.setParameter(i, values[i]);
        }
        List<AttendanceBreakDown> list =  query.list();
        return list;
   }
   ```

Now I can use JPA 2.0 through EntityManager and step down to Hibernate's Session to have access to all Hibernate features that JPA 2.0 does not offer.

Comment: OK, I see. I was curious about it, and your own answer confused me.

So I guess having a .hbm.xml file with the same package and name as your @Entity is sufficient for it to be picked up by Hibernate EntityManager.